# Why is CopyOnWriteArrayList safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have an array **[a, b, c, d]**

Thread **A** wants to add a new element **e** to the set. [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) creates new array, copies all values from the old array, adds new element **e** and then updates the reference to the new array with element **e** in it.

While thread **A** copies values, thread **B** also wants to add a new element **f**. So it copies all values without **e** adds **f** and then updates the reference to the array.

In this case the array may not have element **e** in it.

How thread safety is achieved here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the modification methods (`add`, `set`, `remove`, `clear`, etc.) are guarded by locks. That's how you have the correct write ordering. However, because of the copy-on-write, that means that each of the backing arrays is effectively immutable, which means that read-only operations don't need locking. (The field holding the backing array is `volatile`, so you still get the correct *happens-before* behaviour.)